# Powershell unescaping backslash-escaped code

Tags: powershell

I want to unescape PHP code that has been escaped with backslashes.  I'm using Powershell to do this.

Backslash characters can be used to escape a number of things, but in my sample data I only see examples of double-quotes being escaped in this manner.   Ideally my code would support the other cases, but this is all I have for now.

```
$test = '<a href=\"some-link\">some-text</a>.'
$test -replace '\"', '"'
```

The output of this is not what I expected:

> `<a href=\"some-link\">some-text</a>.`

Expected output:

> `<a href="some-link">some-text</a>.`

I've also tried

```
$test -replace "`\`"", "`""
```

But the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems backslashes are also used for escaping backslashes in powershell.  Therefore the correct code is

```
$test -replace '\\"', '"'
```